# I want to change the css of a page on a the click of a link

Tags: html, css

So I want to make different versions of my website (color wise) with only html and css if possible.

How do I make it so if someone clicks an icon the color of the page will change
Website: ibrepository.com

Comment: show what have you tried till now or what are you planning to do.

Comment: can you show us the code or tell us were you want this link to be placed

Comment: if you login to forum.ibrepository.com using user: test and password: test you can see that you can change the theme of the website based on one click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do so by using [.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/) function of jQuery.

```js
$(function() {

  $("#myAnchor").click(function() {
    $("#someDiv").css("color", "yellow");
  });

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <a href="#" id="myAnchor">Click here </a>

  <div id="someDiv">
    Hello World
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

**[Working DEMO here](https://jsfiddle.net/fjq83o8p/5/)**

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is with javascript.

see this example here: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_style_create_elmnt

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with JavaScript and JQuery as stated above, but if you wish for the SIMPLEST, not best, way, simply make another cloned HTML page and give the elements which you want to change a separate class and change the class as wished on the CSS page. Then you add the link to that page as a button, or in your case the already existing button which you want the CSS to change when clicked.

EDIT: This will not require Java or JQuery.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend the javascript method; however, if you are looking for other options... note: this is not how I would set this up; however, trying to give you an answer that gets as close to your actual request.  **You requested a way to edit this with JUST css and html.**

### Using php

Create the page and css file.  Use a link to change the url.
`page.php?color=yellow`

use `$_GET` to retrieve color and use php to include color stylesheet

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/<?php echo $_GET['color'] ?>.css">`

This will allow you to ONLY use css to modify colors.  You are just using php to link to the right files.

### without php

if your content doesn't change any, this is an option.  Not a good one, but it is the only way to do it with JUST html/css

1. create your initial page, create your initial css.
2. Duplicate both and rename them to color.
3. use links to physically change the page.  The content stays the same
   but the color will be different.