# Can not change attributes of a button using CSS

Tags: html, css

This is my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script src="javascript.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async defer></script>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Random quotes machine</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body onload="startTime()">
    <div id="timer"></div>
    <div id="quotesGoHere">
        <!--Quotes will be displayed here-->
    </div>
    <button type="button" id="buttonAtt" onclick="newQuote()">New Quote</button>
</body>
</html>
```

And here's come my button attribute. There are more, but I cut it.

```
#buttonAtt {
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #ffffff;
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #ffffff;
    box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #ffffff;
    background-color:transparent;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius:0px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft:0px;
    border-top-left-radius:0px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius:0px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright:0px;
    border-top-right-radius:0px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:0px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright:0px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:0px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:0px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft:0px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:0px;
    text-indent:0;
    border:2px solid #ffffff;
    display:inline-block;
```

But the attribute of my button remains default, it doesn't change anything. Can you guys teach me?

Comment: The style you are using seems about right. Are the other styles in the stylesheet getting applied?

Comment: You have all colors set to white. Everything has been set, maybe you just cannot see it.

Comment: `newQuote()` where is the implementation to this method?

Comment: I use an image as background, so it should be ok if the colors are white

Comment: Perhaps my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49087563/7177029) may help you.

Comment: it's in the .js file

Comment: @BoyWithSilverWings the others work well, except this button, I don't know why

Comment: Try with setting only one attribute, like, set the color to red and see if it is getting applied

Comment: Check chrome devtools. Which styles are getting applied to the button?

Comment: no attribute is getting applied :(

Answer (score 0):

I found one solution, but it doesn't make sense. I put an empty CSS attribute above the old one:

```
#buttonAtt{}
```

and it work well, don't know why...

Answer (score -2):

My apologizes I read that wrong. Just give color to your box-shadows

```css
#buttonAtt {
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #cccccc;
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #cccccc;
    box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #cccccc;
    background-color:transparent;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius:0px;
    -moz-border-radius-top-left:0px;
    border-top-left-radius:0px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius:0px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright:0px;
    border-top-right-radius:0px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:0px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright:0px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:0px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:0px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft:0px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:0px;
    text-indent:0;
    border:2px solid #cccccc;
    display:inline-block;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script src="javascript.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async defer></script>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Random quotes machine</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body onload="startTime()">
    <div id="timer"></div>
    <div id="quotesGoHere">
        <!--Quotes will be displayed here-->
    </div>
    <button type="button" id="buttonAtt" onclick="newQuote()">New Quote</button>
</body>
</html>
```